# PHP Send Whatsapp Messages

Tags: php, whatsapp, whatsapi

Is there any way to send a WhatsApp message via php nowadays? There were a lot of PHP libraries before, but now they all no longer work or are forced to stop. For a small project I need to send small messages and a year ago it was possible with the [Chat API](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API). Now with the end of the support it is not possible to get it to work. Does anyone know a way to realize that in 2016?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.